# How to start a background Thread within a Flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask, python-multithreading

I wrote a Flask app that is working fine, and I wanted that while it is running, a separate background thread should parallel to it doing some stuff. The problem is, doing this doesn't spawn the thread at all, but I know that my code is right because using the exact same portion of the thread code on a simple python script works as intended.

**app.py**

```
weatherCollectorThread = WeatherDataCollectorThread()
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("Starting Weather Collector Thread...")       
        weatherCollectorThread.start()
        print("Starting the WebApp...")
        app.run(debug=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        try:
            weatherCollectorThread.stop()
        except:
            pass
```

**WeatherDataCollectorThread Class**

```
class WeatherDataCollectorThread:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weatherStations = DBHelper.get_weather_stations()
        self.weatherApiKey = "REDACTED"
        self.baseURL = "SOME URL"
        self.isThreadRunning = False
        self.result_log = open('results.log','a+')

    def storeWeatherData(self,weather):
        conn = DBHelper.get_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather_data(city,country,now_unixtime,last_updated_unixtime,temperature,isDay,condition_text,condition_icon,windspeed,winddir,pressure,precipitation,cloud,humidity) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",[weather['city'],weather['country'],weather['now_unixtime'],weather['last_updated_unixtime'],weather['temperature'],weather['isDay'],weather['condition_text'],weather['condition_icon'],weather['windspeed'],weather['winddir'],weather['pressure'],weather['precipitation'],weather['cloud'],weather['humidity']])
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def collectWeatherData(self):
        self.isThreadRunning = True 
        while self.isThreadRunning: 
            for each_station in self.weatherStations:
                if each_station['isWorking'] != 1:
                    continue
                print("Sending request")
                params = {'q':each_station['location'],'key':self.weatherApiKey}
                resp = requests.get(url=self.baseURL,params=params)
                print("Request received")
                weatherData = json.loads(resp.text)
                location = weatherData['location']
                current = weatherData['current']
                weather = {}
                weather['city'] = location['name']
                weather['country'] = location['country']
                weather['now_unixtime'] = location['localtime_epoch']
                weather['last_updated_unixtime'] = current['last_updated_epoch']
                weather['temperature'] = current['temp_c']
                weather['isDay'] = current['is_day']
                weather['condition_text'] = current['condition']['text']
                weather['condition_icon'] = current['condition']['icon']
                weather['windspeed'] = current['wind_kph']
                weather['winddir'] = current['wind_dir']
                weather['pressure'] = current['pressure_mb']
                weather['precipitation'] = current['precip_mm']
                weather['cloud'] = current['cloud']
                weather['humidity'] = current['humidity']
                self.storeWeatherData(weather)
                print("Data stored\n" + '-'*24)
                self.result_log.write(resp.text + '\n')
                
            sleep(60)

    def start(self):
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.collectWeatherData)
        self.thread.start()

    def join_instrument(self,session):
        conn = DBHelper.get_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE weather_stations SET isWorking=1 WHERE weatherStationID=?",[session['weatherStationID']])
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def detach_instrument(self,session):
        conn = DBHelper.get_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE weather_stations SET isWorking=0 WHERE weatherStationID=?",[session['weatherStationID']])
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def stop(self):
        self.result_log.close()
        self.isThreadRunning = False
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the solution.

You see, **when you use `flask run` to run your web-app, it ignores every single function call in the script and parses through the decorators and starts the app on its own.** So, if you do something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.start()
   someOtherFunction()
```

**Neither the `app.start()` nor the `someOtherFunction()` would start.**

So the solution?

**Simply use `python3 app.py` to run the script.**

... yes, it's that simple :|